# How to Set UITabBarController to not select any Tab (ViewController) when TabBarController comes to View

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.2

I have facing this problem

I need to open a **TabBarController** from a **navigation Controller** (tableView DidSelectRow.....) with Two Tabs, as when **TabBarController** becomes active, it has a Tab selected whether implicitly of explicitly like

```
    [_tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0]
```

But want when the TabBarController becomes active, none of the tabs are selected, instead, the view contains a background image with tabs in bottom. The tab is selected and activated only when it is tabbed.

There a Way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Make a UIViewController you want to be shown if none of the tab bar items are selected. The make:

```
MyNoSelectedViewController *myViewController = [[MyNoSelectedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyNoSelectedViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:nil];
[self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:myViewController];
```

Hope it helps.